# How to modify PATH for Homebrew?

Tags: ruby, path, homebrew

Trying to install ruby 1.9.3, read that I need to install homebrew first. Ran brew doctor, and it's giving me a bunch of warnings. One of which is:

> Warning: /usr/bin occurs before /usr/local/bin This means that
>   system-provided programs will be used instead of those provided by
>   Homebrew. The following tools exist at both paths:
>
> ```
> easy_install
> easy_install-2.6
> ```
>
> Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin is ahead of
>   /usr/bin in your PATH.

How does one do what it's asking here?

Comment: [@AristotlePagaltzis](http://stackoverflow.com/users/9410/aristotle-pagaltzis)'s [answer on SuperUser](http://superuser.com/a/580611/86416) gives the best solution in my opinion, allowing your system apps to continue using `/usr/bin`, while you ***selectively symlink*** the Homebrew executables that you want to use instead of the Apple-shipped versions, such as Git.

Comment: @mrdavidjcole: fengd did not answered that question?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 308, accepted):

open your /etc/paths file, put /usr/local/bin on top of /usr/bin

```
$ sudo vi /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

and **Restart the terminal**, @mmel

Comment: Reload the environment or start a new terminal after making this change.

Comment: Disagree with this - should use the below answer - time machine etc will not pick this change up I think as outside user folder.

Comment: This is also the best solution I've found if your problem is that RVM and Homebrew both seem to be competing for same real estate in your .bash_profile file.

Comment: I would NOT edit /etc/paths; instead, use the .profile / .bash_profile methods described elsewhere (e.g., answer by @avelis below or for a more paranoid approach, see the first comment referencing AristotlePagaltzis answer on SuperUser.

Comment: You may want to try using the nano terminal text editor instead of via. I found this to be easier to use. "sudo nano /etc/paths" instead of "sudo vi /etc/paths".

Comment: Why edit /etc when you could just configure it to the local user account. I'm with the others who disagree that this is the best solution.

Answer (score 81):

There are many ways to update your path. Jun1st answer works great. Another method is to augment your `.bash_profile` to have:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"
```

The line above places `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/sbin` in front of your `$PATH`. Once you [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command)) your `.bash_profile` or start a new terminal you can verify your path by [echo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Echo_(command))'ing it out.

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Users/<your account>/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

Once satisfied with the result running `$ brew doctor` again should no longer produce your error.

This blog post helped me out in resolving issues I ran into. http://moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Comment: @JanuszChudzynski For Jun1st's solution, it might be that you have to restart the command line session in order to see the change.

Comment: Recent versions of homebrew day: *Consider setting your PATH so that /usr/local/bin occurs before /usr/bin. Here is a one-liner: `echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile`*. Which is basically what this answer suggests.

Comment: However I doubt it is the right way. See below:
Before change:`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`
change: `echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH >> ~/.bash_profile`
After change: `/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin`

This means that if a command is not found in /usr/local/bin it might get searched twice before it is found in another path.

I think it is better to change the `/etc/paths` file

Comment: $ echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile gives me   $PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile -bash: $: command not found

Comment: @rpeg I am sure if you web search for tutorials there is an abundance of resources, but here is one I know of. http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/272346-bash-101-working-at-the-cli

Answer (score 23):

Just run the following line in your favorite terminal application:

```
echo export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

Restart your terminal and run

```
brew doctor
```

the issue should be resolved

Comment: If you are using zsh use this command
echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc

Comment: Was searching everywhere for a solution, and no one mentioned brew doctor until I found this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

open bash profile in textEdit

open -e .bash_profile

Edit file or paste in front of PATH
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin:**/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin**

save & close the file

*To open .bash_profile directly open textEdit > file > recent

Answer (score 0):

To avoid unnecessary duplication, I added the following to my ~/.bash_profile

```
case ":$PATH:" in
  *:/usr/local/bin:*) ;;     # do nothing if $PATH already contains /usr/local/bin
  *) PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH ;;  # in every other case, add it to the front
esac
```

Credit: https://superuser.com/a/580611