# How do I resolve this conda-related brew doctor error?

Tags: path, homebrew, conda, zsh

I've read earlier threads with seemingly related errors, although I'm somewhat skittish about making changes based on what I see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12861422/how-to-fix-paths-to-solve-homebrew-doctor-warnings) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343834/how-to-modify-path-for-homebrew?rq=1), mainly because I'm afraid of breaking things.

I use conda to manage environments on my Mac but there are some packages that aren't available on conda-forge etc., which is why I've had to use Homebrew.

Running `brew doctor` gives me the errors below, even after `brew update`. I'm running zsh if it matters, and here's what my $PATH looks like. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
echo $PATH |tr : '\n' 
/usr/local/anaconda3/bin
/usr/local/anaconda3/condabin
/usr/local/anaconda3/bin
/usr/local/anaconda3/bin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Here's what `brew doctor` yields:

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and which additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew-provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/icu-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/krb5-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/freetype-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/xslt-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/libpng16-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python3.7-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/libpng-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/xml2-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python3.7m-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python3-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/curl-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/ncursesw6-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/pcre-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/nspr-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/ncurses6-config
  /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/nss-config
```

Answer (score 1):

These messages are completely normal. They haven't caused any problems for me so far. I suggest you just ignore them. `brew doctor` is more of a verbose log than urgent issues with your environment.