# Homebrew - Correcting warning after running Brew Doctor - Altering Path (/user/bin) issue

Tags: ruby, bash, path, terminal, homebrew

**Context**

- I'm getting this error, when running the `Brew Doctor` command in the
  terminal after installing `homebrew`(https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew):

  [image]
- To fix this issue I'm following the instructions here :
  [How to modify PATH for Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343834/homebrew-wants-me-to-amend-my-path-no-clue-how)
- When I type in `sudo vi /etc/paths` to the terminal (I'm on the root), which by the way is part of the answer given in the StackOverflow question I reference above, I get this:

[image]

- When I quit the terminal and type in `Brew Docotor` I still get the
  same warning.

**Questions**

- Main Question: What am I doing wrong?
- Ancillary Question: Why in the terminal do I not have the ability to type anything after running the command?
- Ancillary Question: Why is there all this white space and the ~ characters after running the command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running this command:

`echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile`

fixed the issue for me. I found it at this website: http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/ via [How to modify PATH for Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343834/homebrew-wants-me-to-amend-my-path-no-clue-how)