# Problems after Homebrew uninstall

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, homebrew

I was following a tutorial on updating my Mac to PHP 5.4. Things were going well until I had to step away. Now I don't remember where I left off and couldn't find the same tutorial any more. I did get as far as creating the my_phpinfo.php file, but when I brought it up, it showed 5.3.

I end up digging and digging, then turning to Homebrew. I installed Homebrew and had the standard

> Consider amending your PATH so that /usr/local/bin is ahead of /usr/bin in your PATH

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343834/homebrew-wants-me-to-amend-my-path-no-clue-how) and it didn't work. I found the wiki for Homebrew uninstall and think I'm in worse shape. After trying to reinstall, I get

```
-bash: curl: command not found
-bash: ruby: command not found
```

I decided to try to restart Apache

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

Now I'm stuck. Can anyone help?

Comment: What does your /etc/paths file contain?

Comment: Did a bit more digging. I'm fairly certain that my paths are now screwed up. That is seeing that -bash won't recognize any commands...  Unless you can tell me another way to ls that may work, ls isn't working either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have erased your /etc/paths file. Your path specifies places to look for programs so that you don't have to type the full path every time you wish to use them. NOTE: typing /bin/bash and /bin/ls should work for you...

I suggest you open the /etc/paths file in a text editor and check that it looks like this:

```
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin
```

To do this from the command line you would need to type:

```
/usr/bin/nano /etc/paths
```

If you prefer to use vim then exchange nano for vim and if you need elevated permissions then prefix the command with "/usr/bin/sudo".

After you've done this close and reopen the terminal and you should find the terminal working normally again.

If this doesn't work, your path will most likely be being set in one or many of: /etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile. Check these files exist and if they do, check for mentions of PATH in them and ensure it is getting set with the correct values.

Comment: Well that did get me in to edit paths. You were right, `/usr/local/sbin` was missing. Restarted terminal. Went into `/etc/` and used `ls`  `-bash: ls: command not found`

Comment: Does this help? 
`$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/username/Library/Application`

Comment: yes it does. "ls" is in "/bin" and that's not on your path. Also "/usr/local/sbin" isn't mentioned... Can you show me what's in /etc/paths please?

Comment: I was able to edit per your instructions.
`/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
/usr/local/sbin`

Comment: Can you look and see whether the file ~/.bash_profile exists in on your system? If it does, open it and check to see you see the line starting "export $PATH" exists. If it does either remove it or ensure all of the /etc/paths entries are included.

Comment: Hey, I think I answered a bit too fast. Although that is the contents of path. 

When I started terminal this morning I notices a message. 
`-bash: export: 'Support/GoodSync:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin': not a valid identifier`

Comment: Okay, that means your path is being set in a script that runs on the Terminal launch. Most likely it will be in one or many of: /etc/profile, ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login or ~/.profile. Check these files exist and if they do, check for mentions of PATH in them and ensure it is getting set with the values I put in my answer.

Comment: /etc/profile : `# System-wide .profile for sh(1)

if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then
        eval `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`
fi

if [ "${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then
        [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc
fi`

Comment: ~/.bash_profile :

`export PATH="/Users/adambchase/Library/Application Support/GoodSync":$PATHexport PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/adambchase/Library/Application Support/GoodSync:/$
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/Users/adambchase/Library/Application Support/GoodSync:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/adambchase/Library/Application`

~/bash_login :

`EMPTY`

~/.profile :

`EMPTY`

Comment: Got rid of the first 2 lines in the .bash_profile. That got rid of the export error. Was unsure of the 3rd line though. Restarted Term, no export error on startup.