# Python default site-package directory changed after installing Ruby

Tags: python, ruby, macos, path

I have spent a few hours trying to solve this problem but didn't manage yet. I figure my question is a bit specific to my own mac configuration and I need a more detailed instruction.

So my problem is that I installed Ruby using home-brew, for some reason, this installation changed my default python site-package directory. Before I have Ruby, my terminal python will automatically call the site-package from the path '/Users/xxxxxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages'. However, it now will use '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'. I tried three different ways to solve this issue but all failed:

1 use Canopy Terminal like this [Set Canopy Preference](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469730-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-), but this method point to another directory '/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages', which is not i want either.

2 change the bash_profile like this [amend path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19102869/setting-path-in-terminal), but by just putting the # in every line of the bash_profile, it still use directory '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages'. Btw, my bash_profile and $PATH looks like this before:
[image: bash_profile before]
[image: path before]
and looks like this 
[image: bash_profile now]
[image: path now]

3 add the path '/Users/xxxxxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages' into sys.path, which look like this now:

[image]

But none of those worked. How can I make my terminal point to the path '/Users/xxxxxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages' now? Or ultimately, what should I do to clean up those different site-packages and use the one I only need?

Thank you for any help!

Comment: export the path in your .bashrc etc..

Answer (score 1):

On a mac by default the path is `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/foo.egg`.
Before doing anything, in terminal, start a new Python session and do

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

If the paths are of the form `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/foo.egg`, then just follow [link](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469730-Make-Canopy-User-Python-be-your-default-Python-i-e-on-the-PATH-)

tl;dr

Basically add this to your `bash_profile`,

```
source [...] /activate
VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1 source [...] activate
```

Comment: Thanks @bk2dcradle. But I was not sure what you mean by "the paths are of the form /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/foo.egg". Basically I want to change the path "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/" to the path "/Users/xxxxxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages", and I don't want to use the path "/Applications/Canopy.app/appdata/canopy-1.5.2.2785.macosx-x86_64/Canopy.app/Contents/lib/python2.7/site-packages".

Comment: Start a python session and do `import sys` `sys.prefix`, and tell me what you see

Comment: I see : '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7'

Comment: To change the path from the one you mentioned for the current session, do this, `import sys`, `sys.path.insert(0, "/Users/xxxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages")`, Then try importing a module from that directory.

Comment: For a more permanent fix, and if previous way worked use [site](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html) tl;dr do this in terminal in your case, `echo "/Users/xxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages" >> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/usrlocal.pth`.

Comment: Thank you bk2dcradle! This works. But is it possible to also make my terminal current session (not the python session) import modules from "/Users/xxxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages"? I'm asking this because normally I use terminal to start "ipython notebook", and I import the modules on the html notebook from the path  "/Users/xxxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages". But now I can't directly command "ipython notebook" in terminal. I still like to keep doing it  that way if it is possible. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I just saw this before I type my last question! I think this answers it but I tried and I got this "-bash: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/usrlocal.pth: Permission denied".

Comment: This should answer it use `sudo echo "/Users/xxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages" >> /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/usrlocal.pth`

Comment: unfortunately, adding "sudo" doesn't work. It still says "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/usrlocal.pth: Permission denied".

Comment: Then do it by first navigating `cd /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/`, then `sudo vim usrlocal.pth`, enter password, paste `/Users/xxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages`

Comment: Now my python can import directly from "/Users/xxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages ". Thanks a lot!  However, and I'm sorry about it, I don't think this solved all my issues. I still can't directly launch "ipython notebook" from terminal. I need to directly launch "ipython notebook" because all my previous code are in the notebook format. The "ipython" module exist in " /Users/xxx/canopy/lib/python2.7/site-packages" but not "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/".

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

added to the bash_profile this line " export PATH="$HOME/canopy/bin:$PATH" ", and uncomment all other lines in bash_profile.