# Can't run psql with postgres running as launch daemon

Tags: postgresql-9.1, macports, launchd

This is the third time I'm setting up Postgres on a new machine (OS X 10.9 this time), and the third time I'm having problems with the connection.

Basically, I'm at the point where I've created a database cluster and can start postgres using:

```
postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data
```

But I want it to run in the background as a launch daemon, so I

```
sudo launchctl load -w /Library/LaunchDaemons/org.macports.postgresql91-server.plist
```

It seems like the daemon is launched successfully. But when I type `psql` I get the same old error message I've been dealing with every single time I try to set up Postgres:

```
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory. Is the server running locally and accepting connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Any ideas on what might be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `psql` you're running is the old version bundled by Apple in Mac OS X and added to the default PATH. Use the one from Homebrew, by fixing your path or entering the path specifically.

Alternately, explicitly connect to the server by overriding the default socket directory:

```
psql -h /tmp
```

See also:

- [this superuser answer](https://superuser.com/questions/324616/how-should-i-set-the-path-variable-on-my-mac-so-the-hombrew-installed-tools-are/580611#580611)
- [How to modify PATH for Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10343834/398670)

**Update**:

In this case it looks like the server is genuinely not starting. Check the permissions on the data directory (apparently `/usr/local/pgsql/data`) and check the Console.app logs for relevant messages from launchd.

**Update**:

You must fix the permissions so the postgres user (or postgres_, depending on how you installed) has ownership. Check the launchd config file to see what user it runs as, and sudo chown -R postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data to change ownership. Replace postgres with postgres_ if that's what your launchd config says

Comment: I'll try this shortly. I used Macports, rather than Homebrew, but I guess it's the same thing in this regard.

Comment: So, it seems like the path is set up correctly. `psql -h /tmp` does not work. My path begins with `/opt/local/lib/postgresql91/bin`. Not really sure where to continue debugging from here.

Comment: Also, when I grep the launchctl services, `orc.macports.postgresql91-server` displays `-` as its status. It does not change when I start, stop, load or unload the process.

Comment: Check the PostgreSQL server error log files, then. Anything there? Or in the Consle logs? (Wondering about data-directory permissions issues in particular).

Comment: The `/opt/local/var/log/postgresql91/postgres.log` file is empty. Is there any other log file?

Comment: Additionally, `whereis psql` displays an empty result. On my other machine where Postgres is set up properly, the same command displays `/usr/bin/psql`. Is that relevant?

Comment: Ok, so I can connect using `postgres -D /usr/local/pgsql/data`, but the launchdaemon doesn't seem to be working. Any clues?

Comment: Check the Console.app logs for launchd. I bet the data directory permissions are wrong.

Comment: Well, if it's not starting and there's nothing in the PostgreSQL logs there should be in Console.app logs. Anyway, what's `ls -ld /usr/local/pgsql/data` report?

Comment: `drxw----- 18 myappleusername wheel 612 date /usr/local/pgsql/data/`

Comment: @trevorDashDash Well, there's your problem. You must fix the permissions so the `postgres` user (or `postgres_`, depending on how you installed) has ownership. Check the launchd config file to see what user it runs as, and `sudo chown -R postgres /usr/local/pgsql/data` to change ownership. Replace `postgres` with `postgres_` if that's what your launchd config says.

Comment: Ok, that actually did it when I restarted launchd. Thanks a ton! This is way over my head.