# Meld installed with Homebrew "Can't bind translation domain" Error

Tags: git, merge, homebrew, conflict, meld

I installed the git merge-conflict resolution tool Meld using homebrew.

"brew install meld"

Following install, error thrown when attempting to fix a merge conflict. 
Running on OSX 10.9.4.
Ideas?

## Error in its entirety:

===================================

Couldn't bind the translation domain. Some translations won't work.

'module' object has no attribute 'bindtextdomain'

/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/**init**.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)

/usr/local/Cellar/meld/1.8.6/libexec/bin/meld:155: GtkWarning: gtk_icon_theme_get_for_screen: assertion 'GDK_IS_SCREEN (screen)' failed
  gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/meld/1.8.6/libexec/bin/meld", line 155, in 
    gtk.icon_theme_get_default().append_search_path(meld.paths.icon_dir())

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append_search_path'

===================================

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever tried running "brew doctor" to check your system?  It can solve most of the problems, indicating that your problem might be caused by using a wrong version of python programs.  It will suggest you to modify your path in ~/.bashrc

See this:

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/10908

Read this as well:

[How to modify PATH for Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343834/homebrew-wants-me-to-amend-my-path-no-clue-how)

=====

That is what I get in case of path conflicts:

meld
Couldn't bind the translation domain. Some translations won't work.
'module' object has no attribute 'bindtextdomain'

(process:690): Gtk-WARNING **: Locale not supported by C library.
    Using the fallback 'C' locale.
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gobject/**init**.py:115: Warning: attempting to add an interface (GtkEditable) to class (HistoryFileEntry) after class_init
  type_register(cls, namespace.get('**gtype_name**'))
/usr/local/Cellar/meld/1.8.6/libexec/bin/meld:172: GtkWarning: Could not find the icon 'application-x-meld-comparison'. The 'hicolor' theme
was not found either, perhaps you need to install it.
You can get a copy from:
    http://icon-theme.freedesktop.org/releases
  gtk.main()

Answer (score 0):

I had to put `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in my `PATH`. I did this by adding to my `.bash_profile`:

```
PATH="`brew --prefix`/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

**meld** has got a natively compiled version on Mac OS X now.  Check the github below:

https://github.com/yousseb/meld

And please do post back comments and suggestions.  In additional, if you need to call up meld from other programs, you need to add yourself a shellscript to translate parameters sent from git to meld.  You can look for one on Google.