# XCode mvn: No such file or directory

Tags: xcode, macos, maven, j2objc

I have installed Maven on my Mac OSX Yosemite, maven -version on terminal displays the version. Initially I tried with brew even that was successful but it did not resolve the issue in XCode. 
I am new to Mac OSX as well as XCode, so please step by step guide is much appreciated. I am not sure if any plugin is required to build the project

```
Building j2objc annotations
mvn generate-resources dependency:sources
make[1]: mvn: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [/Users/salmansiddiqui/Documents/xcode/j2objc-0.9.4/java_deps/build_result/.maven_generate] Error 1
make: *** [java_deps_dist] Error 2
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
```

Answer (score -1):

Wherever brew put the mvn executable, that path needs to be added to your PATH environment variable. Here is a StackOverflow answer that should help: [How to modify PATH for Homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343834/homebrew-wants-me-to-amend-my-path-no-clue-how). You'll probably need to log out and back in for the new path to be included. To verify your paths are set up correctly, in a Terminal window run "mvn -v", which displays the version and installation information. The j2objc build should work once "mvn -v" works.

Comment: Later I have installed maven manually and set the path as well. mvn -v shows the version information properly but still XCode compilation is failing with the same error message. I have restarted the system to be sure path is set. Maven version I have installed in 3.0.5

Comment: cd to the j2objc directory in a Terminal window, and run "make dist". That creates a dist/ directory, which is equivalent to the distribution bundles. Or just download a release and unzip it, as building from source is optional.

Comment: Thanks Tom for your help, I was able to build the project after setting the Header Search Paths correctly to dist/include.

Comment: This answer is not really helpful. Its not clear from the comments what the solution was, although it is clear that simply haven mvn on path does not fix the error.