# How to update cURL on OSX El Capitan?

Tags: macos, curl, osx-elcapitan

I'm new using Mac and I'd like to upgrade the available cURL-7.43.0 to the last version cURL-7.47.1? 
I'm looking at some pages, but they say to avoid upgrading the originals on OSX.
Any help please? 
Thanks

Comment: Despite using homebrew, i found the version never matched "which curl", no matter what I did with the $PATH variable.  So now I just give the full path to curl which is the latest version and it works.

Comment: As I understand it, you can't update the base curl version on macs which is why people suggest using Homebrew to install the latest version of curl.

Answer (score 30):

Take a look at installing [homebrew](http://brew.sh), it's a package manager that allow you to install and update binaries without overwriting your original ones.

You need then to prepend your PATH with homebrew's (`/usr/local/bin` by default).
If you don't when you run `curl` the system will fetch the default OSX one (`/usr/bin/curl`) which isn't updated.

Use `which curl` when you're done to check !

Comment: How exactly does one "prepend" the path? Could you expand on this?

Comment: When I do `which curl` I get `/usr/bin/curl` back. However, when I try `brew upgrade curl` it tells me that curl is not installed.

Comment: @MadPhysicist here you go !! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343834/how-to-modify-path-for-homebrew

Comment: @MrKiwi When I place `/usr/local/bin` above `/usr/bin` in the `/etc/paths` and then run `which curl` I still get `/usr/bin/curl` back. It seems that the system is still pulling from the default location. What could be the cause of this?

Comment: @MadPhysicist could you dump your path ? `env | grep -E "^PATH="`

Comment: PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/Users/selfishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/Users/selfishman/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/Users/selfishman/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:/Users/selfishman/.rvm/bin

Comment: Try `brew info curl` to show how curl is installed - normally it is "keg only", meaning it is not on the PATH environment variable, as that command explains.  So you will need to put the cellar-based path to curl shown by that command on your PATH.

Answer (score 24):

I had this issue as well with OSx locating curl at `/usr/bin`. If you install curl with `brew install curl` and then do `brew info curl` it will tell you the following near the bottom of the post-op output:

```
If you need to have this software first in your PATH run:

echo 'export PATH="/usr/local/opt/curl/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bash_profile
```

After running that command to update `~/.bash_profile` you need to source it by executing `. ~/.bash_profile`

Comment: This does not update the `libcurl` header files available for C

Comment: Exactly! and it's very annoying for Git! because Git can't access to certificate managed by KeyChain.

Comment: @RichardMcFriendOluwamuyiwa @JYC True. Included in the brew output is also this `For compilers to find curl you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/curl/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/curl/include"`