# Warning: openssl-1.0.2g already installed when using HomeBrew

Tags: macos, openssl, composer-php, osx-elcapitan

I'm working on OS X 10.11.4. I'm trying to get started with [Zend Framework2](http://framework.zend.com/) and am using the official manual so have installed composer. When installing composer I got this warning:

> The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or
>   TLSv1.1. If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or
>   above.

So I opened Terminal and used the following to check my openssl version:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

So I looked into updating and came across [How to upgrade OpenSSL in OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/126830/how-to-upgrade-openssl-in-os-x) on the Apple Stack Exchange. I then used the following to update HomeBrew and install the latest version of OpenSSL

```
$ brew update
$ brew install openssl
```

But got this warning:

```
Warning: openssl-1.0.2g already installed
```

So then I followed this advice ([Update OpenSSL on OS X with Homebrew](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15185661/update-openssl-on-os-x-with-homebrew) - top answer)

```
$ brew unlink openssl && brew link openssl --force
Unlinking /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2g... 1591 symlinks removed
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2g... 1588 symlinks created
$ which openssl
/usr/local/bin/openssl
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
```

So it seems I have the updated version on my machine but it isn't being used by default?

Sorry for my naivety but I'm a complete beginner.

Can any one tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have two problems. First, you need to get HomeBrew's updated OpenSSL on-path so its used instead of Apple's download version. Second, you need to get PHP to use HomeBrew's version of OpenSSL, and not Apple's downlevel version. This is more than a simple path problem because PHP needs to be built against 1.0.2x.

Comment: For your first issue, see [OpenSSL Version MacOSX Homebrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15185661). Its not clear what's going on with your second issue. You will need to explain the PHP configuration.

Comment: Thanks jww, I have updated any question since following that link. I'm afraid I'm not sure how to explain my php configuration though, would you be able to elaborate please? Many thanks

Comment: See [How should I set the PATH variable on my Mac so the Hombrew-installed tools are found?](http://superuser.com/q/324616) on Super User and [How to modify PATH for Homebrew?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10343834) on Stack Overflow. I've also experienced the `which` behavior you describe. Either reboot the machine, or close the current terminal and open a new one.

Comment: were you able to fix this ?