# How to upgrade OpenSSL version used by PHP?

Tags: php, macos, openssl, composer-php

When I install composer for my mac, error appear with:

> The OpenSSL library (0.9.8zc) used by PHP does not support TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.1.
>   If possible you should upgrade OpenSSL to version 1.0.1 or above.

And I upgrade openssl version with brew.I install again and the same error error message appear.And I check php openssl version with this command.

```
php -r "echo OPENSSL_VERSION_TEXT;"
```

The openssl version within php doesn't change.

How can I upgrade the openssl version within PHP?

Comment: Also see [Warning: openssl-1.0.2g already installed when using HomeBrew](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36372000).