# How do I use the python3 version that is installed in Homebrew instead of the one that is installed in the Library?

Tags: python, macos, terminal, homebrew

My problem is that when I check the `python3` version I get 3.6.0 but when I install `python3` with `HomeBrew` it tells me that I have `python 3.6.3`. installed. How do I get my computer to tell me that I have `python 3.6.3` when I use the `python3 --version` command? As you can see in the image, that is the problem that I have, how do I fix it?

```
python3: stable 3.6.3 (bottled), devel 3.7.0a3, HEAD
Interpreted, interactive, object-oriented programming language
https://www.python.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3 (7,720 files, 109.4MB) 
Built from source on 2016-11-14 at 18:24:57
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3 (7,973 files, 111MB)
Built from source on 2017-12-15 at 10:26:40
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/master/Formula/python3.rb
```

After I typed `brew info python3' then I got the output that you see in the above image.

```
wireless-10-105-105-109:~ johnhsu$ echo $PATH

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

'
Also when I checked what path i have, this is what I got. Which looks very different than what it is supposed to look like, maybe?

When I enter a command which python3 it does this.

```
Johns-Air:~ johnhsu$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
```

However, when I use 'brew info python3', it gives me this:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_3 (7,720 files, 109.4MB)
  Built from source on 2016-11-14 at 18:24:57
/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3 (7,973 files, 111MB) *
  Built from source on 2017-12-15 at 10:26:40
```

Comment: If you only type python3, what version do you see then?

Comment: You might need to update your `PATH` variable, probably to add `/usr/local/bin`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10343834/how-to-modify-path-for-homebrew

Comment: what does `brew info python3` say?

Comment: You might also consider restarting the terminal to make sure references update.

Comment: @Blinxen if I type python3 I get Python 3.6.0

Comment: @hansaplast when i type brew info python3 i get {  File "<stdin>", line 1
    brew info python3
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax }

Comment: @CalvinVanHobbes: you need to type this command into your shell (e.g. bash), not in the python shell

Comment: @hansaplast Sorry! I got { python3: stable 3.6.3 (bottled), devel 3.7.0a3, HEAD }

Comment: can you post the whole output, best into your question as it's multiple lines? It should look [like this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/145481/88103)

Comment: please use copy-paste to show what is shown, no screenshots please

Comment: ok, can you try `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/python --version` or `/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.3/python3 --version`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is your PATH, but don't just go changing it at random... Actually look what you've added to it.

In order of resolution

The **system** Python2.7 - `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`

The **system** Python3.6 - `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin`

Maybe your Homebrew installations - `/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin`

The **system** Python3.5 -
 `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin`

The **system** Python2.7 again - 
`/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin`

Maybe your Homebrew installations again - `/usr/local/bin`

All the other system binaries - 
`/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin`

---

Whenever you type `python3`, the first found occurrence of the System Python is run. And I don't think Macs come with Python3 within `/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework`, so you should at least try to uninstall that.

Even running `python3.6`  would do the same thing.

You must place your Homebrew bin and sbin directories first on the PATH

Personally, I stopped using Homebrew for Python and use [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/)

Answer (score 0):

You have installed two python versions side-by-side and OSX takes the other version as default.

`brew doctor` should confirmed that, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7375583/119861).

What you'd need to do is to put edit your `.bashrc` to put: `/usr/local/bin` ahead of `/usr/bin` in your $PATH.

Comment: Johns-Air:~ johnhsu$ which python
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python
Johns-Air:~ johnhsu$ which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin/python3
Johns-Air:~ johnhsu$ 
 I get this result when I ask which python3

Comment: @CalvinVanHobbes so `brew doctor` did not fix your issue then..?

Comment: yeah, brew doctor didn't fix my problem because my path doesn't point to Homebrew

Comment: @CalvinVanHobbes: oh, silly me. `brew doctor` just *shows* the problem, the problem is solved with adapting path. I now updated my answer