# Homebrew's Version of Ruby Disagrees with ruby -v

Tags: ruby, homebrew

My computer came with Ruby 1.8.7 installed by default. I installed Homebrew and then used it to install the latest version of ruby. When I run the following commands, I get differing responses:

```
brew upgrade ruby
Warning: ruby 2.6.5 is already installed and up-to-date

ruby -v
ruby 2.3.7p456 (2018-03-28 revision 63024) [universal.x86_64-darwin18]
```

Not only do the versions on these two disagree, but neither of them are the most recent version of Ruby (2.7). How do I make sure what version of Ruby I have installed, and use the latest version?

*Note: this question isn't a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3987683/homebrew-install-specific-version-of-formula) because `brew install ruby@2.7.0` and other similar commands have no effect, and also because the main issue is with version disagreement.*

Comment: What's in your `PATH`?

Comment: Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.0` (for example). [Don't](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/psa-do-not-use-system-ruby) [use](https://chrisherring.co/posts/why-you-shouldn-t-use-the-system-ruby) [system Ruby](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2014/05/15/never-use-system-ruby-ever/).

Comment: Homebrew is a community-driven Open Source Project. You are a part of that community. If there is no formula for Ruby 2.7 yet, then the reason is that the community (and that includes *you*) has not done the work yet to update the formula. That is understandable since in many parts of the world, it is currently holiday time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As recommended by @anothermh and @hd1, I used RVM instead of Homebrew:

> Install RVM with `\curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable`; restart your shell; install Ruby with `rvm install 2.6.0` (for example).

Answer (score 2):

My system has:

± /usr/bin/ruby --version

ruby 2.6.3p62 (2019-04-16 revision 67580) [universal.x86_64-darwin19]

± ruby --version

ruby 2.4.7p357 (2019-08-28 revision 67796) [x86_64-darwin19]

The reason for this is the order of the directories in the PATH variable. It's read left-to-right, so if you'd like to make sure homebrew's ruby takes precedence, put 
/usr/local/bin as the **left-most** member of your PATH variable. If you need further assistance, leave a comment.

Comment: I followed [these instructions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10343891/9070242) to find my path file, but the first line already reads `/usr/local/bin`.

Comment: `if [ -x /usr/libexec/path_helper ]; then eval /usr/libexec/path_helper -s fi if ["${BASH-no}" != "no" ]; then [ -r /etc/bashrc ] && . /etc/bashrc fi`

Comment: Kindly execute `/usr/libexec/path_helper -s`?

Comment: `PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Users/{my user}/Desktop/{deleted folder}/tools"; export PATH;` I deleted the folder that has its name replaced with `{deleted folder}` a long time ago.

Comment: I'll echo the suggestion of @anothermh, just install rvm and be happier.